# Meteor - Updating a document setting field to undefined

Tags: meteor

I'm seeing some strange behaviour that I don't understand when updating a document.

Here's the code I'm running:

(someField is set to a Date object)

```
Posts.update(postId, {
  $set: {
    someField: undefined
  }
}, function (err, numberOfDocsUpdated) {
  console.log(err); // null
  console.log(numberOfDocsUpdated); // 1
});
```

This code isn't updating the object even though I don't get an error and the number of documents that were updated is supposedly 1.

I'm using collection2 and simple-schema packages so maybe the problem is there, even though I don't see any messages from the packages when updating the document.

The simpleschema for someField is:
        someField: {
            type: Date,
            optional: true
        }

Any ideas what's going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try unsetting the field instead.

```
Posts.update(postId, {
  $unset: {
    someField: 1
  }
}, ...
```